# Scala Parse Json without knowing schema

Tags: json, scala

I was wondering if there is a parser or an easy way to iterate through a json object without knowing the keys/schema of the json ahead of time in scala.  I took a look at a few libraries like json4s, but it seems to still require knowing the schema ahead of time before extracting the fields.  I just want to iterate over each field, extract the fields and print out their values something like:

```
    json.foreachkey(key -> println(key +":" + json.get(key))
```

Answer (score 2):

In [Play Json](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.2.x/ScalaJson) you'll initially parse your json into a [JsValue](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.0/api/scala/play/api/libs/json/JsValue.html); you can then pattern-match this to determine if it is a [JsObject](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.0.1/api/scala/play/api/libs/json/JsObject.html) (note that you can find the fields of this using `fields` or `value`), a [JsArray](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.0/api/scala/play/api/libs/json/JsArray.html) (again, note the `value`), or a primitive such as [JsString](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.0/api/scala/play/api/libs/json/JsString.html) or [JsNull](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.0/api/scala/play/api/libs/json/JsNull$.html)

```
def parse(jsVal: JsValue) {
  jsVal match {
    case json: JsObject =>
    case json: JsArray =>
    case json: JsString =>
    ...
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If by json you mean any JValue, then [json4s](https://github.com/json4s/json4s) seems to have this functionality out of the box:

```
scala> import org.json4s.JsonDSL._
import org.json4s.JsonDSL._

scala> import org.json4s.native.JsonMethods._
import org.json4s.native.JsonMethods._

scala> val json = parse(""" { "numbers" : [1, 2, 3, 4] } """)
json: org.json4s.JValue = JObject(List((numbers,JArray(List(JInt(1), JInt(2), JInt(3), JInt(4))))))

scala> compact(render(json))
res1: String = {"numbers":[1,2,3,4]}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [liftweb](https://github.com/lift/lift/tree/master/framework/lift-base/lift-json), it allows you to parse the json first into JValue - then extract native scala objects from it, no matter the schema:

```
val jsonString = """{"menu": {
                         |  "id": "file",
                         |  "value": "File",
                         |  "popup": {
                         |    "menuitem": [
                         |      {"value": "New", "onclick": "CreateNewDoc()"},
                         |      {"value": "Open", "onclick": "OpenDoc()"},
                         |      {"value": "Close", "onclick": "CloseDoc()"}
                         |    ]
                         |  }
                         |}}""".stripMargin 

val jVal: JValue = parse(jsonString)

jVal.values
>>> Map(menu -> Map(id -> file, value -> File, popup -> Map(menuitem -> List(Map(value -> New, onclick -> CreateNewDoc()), Map(value -> Open, onclick -> OpenDoc()), Map(value -> Close, onclick -> CloseDoc())))))
```